# Show that if $H_1, H_2$ are Hilbert separable and and $A \in L(H_1, H_2)$ then there is a sequence of finite rank operators $A_n \xrightarrow{s} A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_1, H_2$ be Hilbert separable and and let $A \in L(H_1, H_2)$ be an operator between them.
I want to show there is a sequence of finite rank bounded operators $\{A_n\}$, such that $A_n \xrightarrow{s} A$, which means that for every $x \in H_1$ it satisfies:
$$||A_nx - Ax|| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$$

Well, there is $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ an orthonormal basis for $H_1$ since it's Hilbert separable, so:
$$Ax = \sum_{i=1}^\infty <x,e_i> A(e_i)$$

Then I thought about declaring the projection $A_n$ on $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ by $$A_nx = \sum_{i=1}^n <x,e_i> A(e_i)$$

which is a compact finite rank operator.

Then, I will get:
$$ ||A_nx - Ax||^2 = ||\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty <x,e_i> A(e_i)||^2 = <{\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty <x,e_i> A(e_i), \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty <x,e_j> A(e_j)}> = $$ $$=\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty <x,e_i> \bar{<x,e_j>}<A(e_i),A(e_j)>$$

Here I get stuck with $<A(e_i),A(e_j)>$ and I am not sure how to continue.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $x$. $A(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i e_i$, $A_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i e_i$.

As $A(x) \in H_2$ we have $||A(x)||^2 = ||\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  c_i e_i||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i^2 < \infty$ and thus $\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}c_i^2 \to 0, n\to \infty$.

Hence $$||A(x)  - A_n(x) ||^2 = ||  \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} c_i e_i||^2 = \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}c_i^2 \to 0.$$

Comment: So an orthonormal basis of $H_2$ is used here?

Comment: @GabiG Yes, it's true.